# Xamarin CrossGeeks Geofence Plugin null reference exception

Tags: android, xamarin, geofence

I am using the CrossGeeks Geofence plugin found here:
https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GeofencePlugin
Using the documentation on the home page and the sample found here to build a test app:
https://github.com/domaven/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/Samples/Geofence

I encounter this error when I try to start monitoring a region:

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Plugin.Geofence.GeofenceImplementation.RequestMonitoringStart () [0x00000] in <793ebe419a94494388f459127f8240ff>:0 
  at Plugin.Geofence.GeofenceImplementation.StartMonitoring (Plugin.Geofence.GeofenceCircularRegion region) [0x00061] in <793ebe419a94494388f459127f8240ff>:0 
  at GeoFenceApp.MainPageViewModel.StartStopMonitoring () [0x00027] in C:\Users\ctodd\source\repos\GeoFenceApp\GeoFenceApp\MainPageViewModel.cs:87 }
```

The CrossGeofence object itself is not null and neither is the _myRegion object:
[screenshot of cross geofence object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02CJi.png)
[screenshot of region object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL3wN.png)
I believe I am initialising things correctly according to the documentation and the sample.
I'm using the following permissions, even though I believe only fine_location, coarse_location, read_gservices and boot_completed are necessary:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

A google api key is necessary in the sample because a map is being displayed, but I don't need to display a map. Do I still need this key to access location services?
After the permissions, I'm really not sure what is causing the error, as I've tried to follow the documentation.

Comment: it seems fairly obvious that `_myRegion` must be null, it's the only other object on that line of code

Comment: It isn't. My apologies, I should have included that in the post. Editing now.